# Visual Basic Express 2013 - List Boxes

Tags: c#, jquery

I have to write a program to determine which students have a specified major based upon the button that is clicked. For example, if the *Search Computer Science* button is clicked, then the program should pull all the CS student's names and put them in the results List box. The text box above the results list box should contain the specified major being searched and the text box below should contain a message indicating the total number of students with that specific major. Can someone help me please? Not even sure where to start. Thank you!

I can't upload the picture of my form because of low reputation. but the form has 3 list boxes. The first list box (lstStudents) has all of the students' names. The second list box (lstMajors) is the majors each student belong in. So, the student in Items(0) of the lstStudents list box, is in the major at Items(0) of the lstMajors list box.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to provide a proper answer, but this is what you need to do:

1. When a button is clicked, you need to get the major.
2. Then you need to iterate through all the options in the Majors listbox, and if it matches the major in step 1, then copy/move the student in the students listbox that is at the same position, into the results listbox.
3. Set the value of the top textbox to the major you determined in step 1.
4. Set the value of the bottom textbox the the number of students in the results listbox.

Make sense?

Good luck with your assignment!

Comment: Makes sense I just don't know how to write the code for that so when I go to run the program, and the Search Computer Science is selected, the program automatically displays all of the students in that major and how many.